# How would I get my printToScreenNew() method to print my new generation? The result I am getting is my package name followed by Generation@33909752

Tags: java

```
public Generation newGen() {
    Generation newGen = new Generation();

    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 76; j++) {
            int x = i;
            int y = j;
            int n = numberOfNeighbors(x, y);
            if (gen[i][j] == 'X') {
                if (n == 2 || n == 3) {
                    newGen.gen[i][j] = 'X';
                }
                if (n != 2 || n != 3) {
                    newGen.gen[i][j] = '.';
                }
            }
            if (gen[i][j] == '.') {
                if (n == 3) {
                    newGen.gen[i][j] = 'X';
                }
                if (n != 3) {
                    newGen.gen[i][j] = '.';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newGen;
}
```

//I'm taking a char[][] called gen and passing it to the above method, and it is supposed to return a value of type Generation(the class) and then print it to the console in the method below.

```
public void printToScreenNew() {
    Generation newGen = newGen();
    System.out.print(newGen.toString());
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Comment: Since you didn't override `toString()` in your class it inherited this method from `Object` and thus the result.